# How to replace linked server calls in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

I have two SQL Server database instances - let's call them server A and B.

Sadly, as the user traffic decreases, there is now no need for running two servers anymore. So I'm planning to merge databases on server B to A.

But here's the problem: there are thousands of stored procedures and triggers on server A that connects to server B through linked server and vice versa.

When merged, there is no need to use linked server so I'm going to have to replace all of them.

It might be possible to keep linked server and make it to point itself? But it seems like a bad practice.

How can I effectively replace all of them? Do I have to write thousands of `ALTER` SQL scripts?

Comment: If there is a consistence in the alter procedure, then you could write a C# application and connect to the new database and replace the alter procedure. Its also a good Idea to post some of your alter procedure here so we could have a look if there is to much different between them.

Comment: @Alen.Toma Thank you for your suggestion. Like what you've said, I could make a script or C# program that automates the altering of the procedures. But I was curious if there are any SQL server built-in features for this kind of work.

Comment: Although MS does not officially support creating linked servers that point to the local server, in practice this does work, except for breaking distributed transactions -- but as long as you're not using those it works fine. For this specific scenario you do have to watch out for recursion or duplicated data, in case any procedures could inadvertently end up calling themselves or inserting data twice while trying to do it on the "other" server. Obviously this should only be used as a stepping stone to a more permanent solution, though.

Answer (score 1):

you can configure the link server that is by filling the Data Source with the name of the sql server instance used.

[image]